# Proton Exchange Membrane H2 generator transports too much water to output

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

I am using a PEM cell to generate H2 (eventually D2).  The PEM cell is fed water on the cathode (O2 side) only, but it transports about 3.5x as much water over to the cathode (H2 side) as it actually consumes in electrolysis.

Ultimately I want to have dry gas and want to minimize wastage since heavy water to get D2 is expensive.  The equations for PEM electrolysis suggest that there is no liquid water transported, so I could dry it with desiccant. Actual case seems like I need to separate water from H2 output and recycle it. I only need a small volume so I am looking for simplicity.

Is this the nature of PEM cells or do I have the wrong kind of cell?

Comment: Can osmosis be the reason? As membranes usually have some residual unwanted features. Like membranes for reverse osmosis have residual or being worn out permeability and PEM can manifest something similar.

Comment: I have a little experience PEM \ce{O2}/\ce{H2} cells from teaching in the first year lab. In my experience, you feed the cell with oxygen and hydrogen directly (in out case humid as it come from a previous electrolysis of water) not with water. As a product of the cell reaction you got a small quantity of water but it accumulates if you run the cell for enough time.

Comment: From the structure of the PEM membrane I would not expect migration of water through the cell since it only transports protons but I maybe mistaken.

Comment: I tried applying some back pressure (inflating a balloon, but that had no effect.